# What does rename-to mean in the module tag of a GWT module?

Tags: gwt

What does the rename-to attribute of the module tag in a GWT module mean?  Is it optional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It "causes the compiler to behave as though the module had a different name than the long, fully-qualified name" (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html).  Yes, it's optional, and indeed only recommended for limited use cases.

Comment: Does this effect the host page?  If I had <module rename-to="roflberry"> and my entry point was "PwnCakes.java"> what would the host page entry for with the .nocache.js file look like?

Comment: I thought it affected the final dir of the compiled module. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does affect the directory name.