# GWT [WARN] 404 - GET /birgit.chat.Chat.nocache.js comet

Tags: java, gwt, comet

i can't get a comet chat example to run.
i get this error

> [WARN] 404 - GET /birgit.chat.Chat.nocache.js (127.0.0.1) 1413 bytes

this is how my web.xml looks like

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>chatComet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>net.zschech.gwt.comet.server.CometServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>chatServiceImpl</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>birgit.chat.server.ChatServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>chatServiceImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/birgit.chat.Chat/chat</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my Chat.gwt.xml

```
   <!DOCTYPE module SYSTEM "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-         source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
     <module >
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard" />
<inherits name="net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet" />
<servlet class="birgit.chat.server.ChatServiceImpl" path="/chat"/>
<entry-point class="birgit.chat.client.ChatEntryPoint" />
    </module>
```

Those are packages i use

```
package birgit.chat.client;
package birgit.chat.server;
```

I think there is something wrong with path but i am out of ideas.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should rename your module name in your *.gwt.xml , module has [rename-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152699/what-does-rename-to-mean-in-the-module-tag-of-a-gwt-module) attribute which renames the module. After that you can reference your *.nocache.html with renamed module name.

```
 <module rename-to="chatModule">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard" />
    <inherits name="net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet" />
    <servlet class="birgit.chat.server.ChatServiceImpl" path="/chat"/>
    <entry-point class="birgit.chat.client.ChatEntryPoint" />
 </module>
```

and in your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
src="chatModule/Chat.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: This only works for me if I compile the project each time. By that I mean that if I add a new class (say, an EntryPoint), or if I just simply rename my module, I keep getting 404s until I re-compile everything. Any ideas?

Comment: You should understand how GWT works, if you add EntryPoint class or change module name, it won't work unless you recompile your new module. Because after compiling it will be converted js or other type of resources in that folder. And also i don't think, you do this kind of things very often....

Comment: Hey had a question. Even after I change the path for nocache.js in my html file, it still gives me a 404 with the old path. What's going on?

Comment: Try to open your file in your browser, make sure you renamed the module and you are doing this way and then it should work..